# c++ assignment operator exception safety

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, assignment-operator

Very straight forward question:

What is the reason of requirement that assignment operator must not throw exception?

In same time, the constructor can throw?

---

If you must not throw exception, how one might handle well known "custom" string example if there is not enough memory for buffer allocation?

If you just allocate less or keep old state, but do not throw exception, everything will "look" smooth, but there will be serious (hidden) error.

Comment: There is no such general requirement in C++.

Comment: Hmmm. OK, but why everyone emphasize this?

Comment: Because you do not know what state the object that is being assigned to remains after the exception? State before the assignment? State after the assignment?

Comment: A quote or two would help.

Comment: if an exception is thrown during execution of the function, there is no telling what the state of the object is; we can only assume that it is in such a bad state (ie, it violates some of its own invariants) as to be unusable. If the object is in a bad state, it might not even be possible to destroy the object without crashing the program or causing MyArray to perhaps throw another exception. 
And we know that the compiler runs destructors while unwinding the stack to search for a handler. If an exception is thrown while unwinding the stack, the program necessarily and unstoppably terminates.

Comment: @n.m. this is sure a reason, but is not requirement.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Any function is potentially able to leave objects in an known state. Assignment is not special.

Comment: @n.m. true, my point was my personal opinion, however - since assignment operators are automatically generated where possible, the caller is not aware of the throw semantics, whereas a when calling a function he is. That is just my two cents:)

Comment: thanks both, I gathered the information I need. @n.m. - if you want, make answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis This is a balid point, automatically generated assignment operators are potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no such requirement. It is perfectly OK for an assignment to throw. In many cases throwing is unavoidable (e.g. when assignment must allocate some memory and there's none left).

What assignment should never do is leave an object in an undefined state. It must either successfully assign a new value, or leave the object in its original state (or perhaps some other valid state, which is less desirable) and throw.

This semantic is often implemented by the copy-and-swap idiom. The copy stage can throw. This leaves the assignee intact. The swap stage must never throw.

Comment: A possible reason for wanting assignment operators to not throw is that the nothrow-ness of the constructors and assignment operators "leaks" up to a container that contains those objects. There is a type trait `is_nothrow_move_assignable` which is apparently desirable to have

Comment: @MattMcNabb Moving is not copying. Copying can throw, moving shouldn't.

Comment: move assignment is a type of assignment, OP was not asking about copy-assignment specifically. In fact the usual implementation of the copy-and-swap idiom that you mention, provides move assignment.

Comment: OP asks about all assignment. Copy-and-swap provides first and foremost copy assignment. It was the cade long before move operations were invented. It will throw if the copy constructor throws (most do as we have seen). You can use this idiom to do move assignment but then it will throw too. Move assignment can be done with just swap, no copy needed.

Comment: We still call it "copy and swap" when using the same code for move assignment, even though it is a move instead of a copy